# How to make getter and setter methods in QT creator automatically

Tags: c++, qt, ide, qt-creator

I am wondering if there is any way in Qt creator IDE to Make the getter and setter function automatically if we ave already declared the variable .

Comment: Which Qt creator are you using?

Comment: QT is QuickTime, correct is Qt

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Qt version 2.3.x above your should easily do it using following.

Right click on your `class member variable`. You will see `Refactor` then `Generate Getter and Setter member function`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without your mouse.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and select `Create Getter and Setter Member Functions`.